# Freemember and custom member fields

Tags: members, custom-fields, freemember, registration

I'm using freemember on a user registration form and custom fields are not being passed to the member profile on registration.

I've tried both standard `m_field_id_22` and freemember `member_newsletter` field names but neither are getting saved and the database is logging a value of null.

Any thoughts on solving?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the latest version of Freemember? Are you sure your custom field names are correct? Your code?

Ok, your code was not formatted properly..

```
{exp:freemember:register form_class="form form--standard"  error_handling="inline" return="account/register/thanks" required="first_name|last_name|email|company|address_1|city|postcode" error_delimiters='<span class="error">|</span>'}
<fieldset>
<h3>Do you want to request a trade account?</h3>
<div class="form__group form__group--inline">
{field:trade-account-yes}
<label for="trade-account-yes" class="form__label">Yes</label>
{error:trade-account-yes}
</div>

<div class="form__group form__group--inline">
{field:trade-account-no}
<label for="trade-account-no" class="form__label">No</label>
{error:trade-account-no}
</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<div class="form__group">
{field:accept_terms}
<label for="accept_terms" class="form__label form__label--required">I have read and agree to the <a href="/terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
{error:accept_terms}
</div>
<div class="form__group">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Continue</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
{/exp:freemember:register}
```

Comment: Using 2.3.2

Sample code posted up at https://gist.github.com/cole007/692dc925747ff07136872f096b2a44b0

Comment: From the documentation you can add your own custom fields/markup though? See https://github.com/devdemon/freemember/blob/master/docs/register_tag.md#custom-member-fields

My previous code sample shows using native EE template variables `{m_field_id_23}` but have also tried with `{member_trade_account}` and neither work. Ideally would like control of the markup for these form elements if at all possible

Answer (score 0):

Okay - this was resolved. Was fiddling with MX Notify which was terminating the write to custom fields when you try and send an email. Testing via Ajax was stopping me see the response.

Thanks for time and response on this everyone (in forum and via Slack)